# How to use OR in query with priority?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a simple query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id='x' OR id='y'
```

How to give a priority to get only one of the WHERE clauses?

I mean getting rows with id='x'. Only if there is no row, get row with id='y'.

In other words, do not use id='y' if there is a row for id='x'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only one row, the simplest method is `limit`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table t
WHERE id IN ('x', 'y')
ORDER BY (id = 'x') DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The `id = 'x'` in the `order by` uses the fact that MySQL treats boolean values as integers in a numeric constant.  So "true" is treated as `1` and "false" as `0`.  The `DESC` puts the true values (i.e. `'x'`) first.

If there are multiple possible rows that could be returned, then `NOT EXISTS` is a possibility:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = 'x' or
      (t.id = 'y' and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = 'x')
      );
```

In MySQL, this version might be optimized better using `union all`, if you have an index on `id`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = 'x' 
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.id = 'y' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = 'x');
```

Comment: I want to get multiple row but through above solution I get only row with id='x' not get any row having id='y'.

Comment: @Neha . . .  If you have a row with `'x'`, then you don't want the row with `'y'`, according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement or limit clause. Limit clause is the better option. Do not forget to use order by while using limit clause

```
select * from
(SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id='x' OR id='y')
where
case when id = 'x' then id = 'x'
     when id = 'Y' then id = 'Y' end ;


SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='x' OR id='y' order by id limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to fetch same data with help the Rank basis, And it's support multiple values as well as, based on your select statement.

`SELECT TOP 1 *, (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VAL DESC )) AS RANK_N FROM TEST_TABLE T WHERE  T.ID IN('X','Y') ORDER BY RANK_N`